# Android EditText error underlined

Tags: android, styles

I tried to test my perfectly working app on 6.0 android and this is what i get:

[image: My problem. that error message is underlined]

The main idea that there is no Error message and error message View is underlined.

My edit text looks like this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_grey2"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:theme="@style/EditTextSmartTheme.Dark"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/edit_text_cusror_register"
    android:maxLength="100"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

And selected Style "EditTextSmartTheme.Dark" is:

```
<style name="EditTextSmartTheme.Dark" parent="Widget.AppCompat.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/light_black</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#99afafaf</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/dark_green</item>
    <item name="android:textCursorDrawable">@drawable/edit_text_cusror_register</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/dark_green</item>
</style>
```

When i remove theme Error message shows as it should, but EditText is not styled obviously.

Any ideas?

Support library 23.2.1

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm having this same issue on all my EditTexts in my app. Setting different styles doesn't seem to change this.

Comment: I don't remember actually.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the error is here @drawable/edit_text_cusror_register

Comment: Seriously? How can this be related? Btw, just tried - result is same.